# Eigenvalues when perturbed along anti-diagonal.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hankel-matrices

Given a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots, n$ we know the relationship between $\{\lambda_k\}$ and the eigenvalues of $A + t I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $t$ a scalar. I am wondering what happens when we replace $I$ with the [exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix) $E$. That is, can we say anything about the eigenvalues of $A + t E$ in relation to the eigenvalues of $A$?

---

**Context:**

I am trying to prove (not sure that assertion is true or not) that singular Hankel matrices can be made invertible by perturbing the values of its antidiagonal entries (just like a singular $A$ can be made invertible by a perturbation $A + tI$).

$$\begin{bmatrix}
f(2) & f(3) & f(4) &\dots &f(n+1) \\
f(3)  & f(4) & \dots &  & f(n+2) \\
\vdots & &  & & \vdots \\
f(n+1) &  f(n+2) & \dots & & f(2n)
\end{bmatrix}$$

So within this context, $A$ has more structure than as stated above.

Comment: regarding context:  $E$ is involutive... why not just multiply $(H+tE)$ by $E$ to recover $(A+tI)$ where $A$ is Toeplitz?  Up to a sign this preserves the determinant which is more than enough to deal with singularities.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, that is what I ended up doing in the end, but couldn't find a nice characterization of $A + tE$ for general $A$.